# Meteor less source map don't get loaded in the client

Tags: node.js, meteor, less, source-maps

I try to get less source maps working in my project but they don't seem to get passed to the client.

```
> meteor --version
> Release 0.8.1.3

> lessc --version
> lessc 1.7.0 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]

> less .meteor/packages |grep less
> less

> ls .meteor/local/build/programs/client
> -rw-r--r--   1 mhhf staff 342679 Jun  6 13:05 473be00fc614aeff1b93b555c76b905fcc71e56b.css
> -rw-r--r--   1 mhhf staff 463306 Jun  6 13:05 473be00fc614aeff1b93b555c76b905fcc71e56b.css.map

> less .meteor/local/build/programs/client/program.json
> ...
> {
  "path": "473be00fc614aeff1b93b555c76b905fcc71e56b.css",
  "where": "client",
  "type": "css",
  "cacheable": true,
  "url": "/473be00fc614aeff1b93b555c76b905fcc71e56b.css",
  "sourceMap": "473be00fc614aeff1b93b555c76b905fcc71e56b.css.map",
  "sourceMapUrl": "/473be00fc614aeff1b93b555c76b905fcc71e56b.map",
  "size": 342679,
  "hash": "2aabe450770c6a0872fa79545aaf3f06523197d8"
},
> ...
```

But somehow the .css file is successfully loaded and the .css.map not.
Where should i look for the error?

Comment: turn sourcemap support on in your browser?

Comment: forgot to mention that they are on and i see them in other projects, just not in this one

Comment: check in the chrome's network manager that file 473be00..356b.css.map is in fact loaded? Check if it works in Chrome vs Firefox. Try Chrome Canary.

Comment: thanks for the tip with canary, but in all browsers (forefox, chrome, canary) 473be00..356b.css.map don't get loaded and isn't displayed in the network manager

Comment: I don't know then. You would need to provide a good reproduction if you want anyone to look at it. Unless you are running your app in production mode, it should serve sourcemaps correctly.

Comment: @user1497164 Did you get anywhere with this issue?